# iTunes Connect Testflight builds were missing after successfully submitted a build

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, app-store-connect, testflight

I was submitting my projects earlier and I noticed that after submission, the build was on "processing" state for a while. Came back, and the build went missing. I tried a couple of times, and succeeded but still, after the processing state, the build still won't go to the Testflight iOS Build section.

I used Xcode 8 to submit my build. Swift 3 and iOS 10 was the selected build target for the app.

However, I tried submitting a different app which supports iOS 9.3 and below using Application Loader 3.6 from Xcode 8 Developer tools, and succeeded to enable Internal testing option from the Testflight section. I found no documentation regarding this issue yet.

Retried the whole process necessary to submit the app

e.g.

- change the bundle ID
- generate new provisioning profiles
- make a new app in ItunesConnect
- setup Internal testers
- uploaded a build using Xcode 8 or Application Loader
- etc.

But after that, still no build in Testflight. :( Too bad Apple never send me notifications on what the real status of the build was.

Comment: i am facing the same issue now, did you find any way for it ?